# How can I use devise helper in netzke?

Tags: devise, netzke

I'm using Devise and Netzke gems. My rails version is 3.1.1

I want to access a devise helper (current_user) in netzke component.

But it not in model or views. It in rails_root/app/component/some_component.rb

How can I call helper method? Thanks.

There is my code....

```rb
# app/component/note_grid.rb
class NoteGrid < Netzke::Basepack::GridPanel
  js_property :title, "Note"

  model "Note"

  def configuration
    super.merge(
      # I want to call helper method here.
      :strong_default_attrs => {:user_id => current_user.id},  
      :columns => [{:name => :updated_at, :header => "Date - Time", :format => "d M Y - h:i A",  :width => 200}, :description],
      :add_form_config => {:items => [:description]},
      :edit_form_config => {:items => [:description]}
    )
  end
end
```

In Views

```rb
# app/views/main/index.html.erb

<%= netzke :main_container, :class_name => "NoteGrid" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current user instance via `Netzke::Core.current_user`
It can also be useful to access the netzke controller instance, which can be done via `Netzke::Core.controller`

Comment: These methods are both no longer present in the `Netzke::Core` module, so how do you solve this now? In netzke_demo `current_user` is defined in the `Application` component. I could do the same. But do I have to define the `current_user` helper in all of my components then? I can simply include a module for that if that is the best approach for now.

Comment: Use Netzke::Base.controller